# What is the simplest way to obtain function obect of a given function?

Tags: functions, placeholder

Suppose I have a function `p` of some arguments:

```
p[x_,y_]:= (* something *)
```

Now I with to pass this function as an object to another function, like derivative:

```
Derivative[0, 2][p[#1, #2] &]
```

Here I used an expression

```
p[#1, #2] &
```

to create a function object.

Can I form it simpler? Neither `p` not `p&` worked.

What if I want to pass a function of variable number of arguments to another function?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by `p` didn't work? I tried `p[x_, y_] := x^5 y^7;
Derivative[0, 2][p]` and it gives the correct answer.

Comment: If you want to pass the derivative function to another function, just define `d02p = Derivative[0, 2][p]` and pass `d02p` to another function.

Answer (score 1):

You can define partial derivatives in specified slots without using `#1` or `#2`:

```
p[x_, y_] := x^5 y^7;
d02p = Derivative[0, 2][p];
d02p[a, b]
```

which returns

```
42 a^5 b^5
```

Likewise, to obtain the pure function `fDer` for the mixed partial derivative of a function `f` of vector argument, try this:

```
f[list_] := (Times @@ list)^8;
ind = RandomInteger[{0, 8}, 10];
fDer = Derivative[ind][f];
fDer[Subscript[a, #] & /@ Range[10]]
```

which produces $$122787561599926272000 a_1^7 a_3^6 a_4 a_5^8 a_6^6 a_7^6 a_8^8 a_9^7 a_{10}^3.$$